# Randomly sample point from a 2D pdf image

Tags: random-generation

I have a 2D image, each pixel of it representing a probability. Now I want to randomly select a point from the image, such that the probability of the position of the point follows the pdf of the image.

How Can I do that? An example pdf image is attached.[image]

Comment: You have the probability values for each pixel stored in an array?

Comment: Assuming by "pdf" you mean "probability function," there are a great many solutions.  Which to use depends in part on whether you need just *one* point, as stated, or whether you intend to select *many* points. There are solutions for the latter that are simpler and computationally more efficient than iterating any solution for the former.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to assume that your image is coded numerically as an $n \times m$ matrix of intensity values that are equal to the probabilities.  This means you have a probability matrix:

$$\boldsymbol{P} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
  p_{11} & p_{12} & \cdots & p_{1m} \\
  p_{21} & p_{22} & \cdots & p_{2m} \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  p_{n1} & p_{n2} & \cdots & p_{nm} \\
 \end{bmatrix}.$$

If you don't already have this matrix, first generate it by normalising the intensities of the pixels, so that they add up to one.  Assuming you have this probability matrix, you can generate a random point with these probabilities by using the multinomial distribution $X \sim \text{Mu}(1, \boldsymbol{P})$.  To implement this you will need to map the positions in this matrix format to a single vector of ordered positions (e.g., reading left-to-right across each row), then generate a random value, and then map it back to matrix coordinates (e.g., using modular arithmetic).  It is simple to create a vectorised function in `R` to generate an arbitrary number of points from your image:

```
#Generate k random matrix points from image matrix
#The input object IMAGE is assumed to be your intensity matrix
#The output is a k x 2 matrix of coordinates for each of k coordinates

GENERATE <- function(IMAGE, k) { n <- nrow(IMAGE);
                                 m <- ncol(IMAGE);
                                 OUTPUT <- data.frame(Row = rep(0,k),
                                                      Column = rep(0,k));
                                 RAND <- sample(1:(n*m), size = k, replace = TRUE, 
                                                prob = as.vector(IMAGE))
                                 OUTPUT$Row    <- 1 + RAND %/% n;
                                 OUTPUT$Column <- RAND %% n;
                                 OUTPUT }
```

This function takes an input matrix `IMAGE` and a number `k` and it generates a data frame with $k$ generated values using the image matrix for the probabilities.  For each generated value there is a specified `Row` and `Column` generated.